# How to remove one letter in Jlabel on button click?

Tags: java

`String k=jLabel2.getText();`// getting text eg=abcd

`int kl=k.length()-1;`  // get k's length and remove one letter ,

I need to do this,

```
if jlabel.getText = ABCDE
```

and I want to remove E from `ABCDE`

`eg=abcd` to `abc`

Comment: please reformat this question and show us what you have tried. you will not be handed an answer

Comment: `jlabel.setText(k.subString(0,kl));`

Comment: what matt says and call revalidate on the frame ;)

Comment: @StimpsonCat I'm pretty sure setText takes care of repaint/validation.

Comment: Yes you are, i was not ;)

Answer (score -1):

You need to get back the text, and then substring from the beginning to antepenultimate char :

```
String labeltext = jLabel2.getText();
jLabel2.setText(labeltext.substring(0, labeltext.length() - 1));
```

*antepenultimate = the one before the last one*

Comment: @Krishan I just want to remember you that a forum like this has people who wanted to answer to people like you because they got "thanks" from them with "accepting answers" or "vote up" and it seems that you did none one thme, so think about it please ;) If it helps :)